# Access to image getting blocked by CORS in laravel

Tags: laravel, image, cors, storage

I've 2 web apps, the web is hosting on main domain (butuh.com) using laravel and sub domain (photo.butuh.com) using vue. The problem is when the site access image to print, the site got this error:
`Access to image at 'https://butuh.com/storage/app/public/images/frame/bmxdomo1a-right.png' from origin 'https://photo.butuh.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

In my laravel, i was used package fruitcake/laravel-cors, and this is my cors.php config:
`

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => false,`
```

i was try to insert the main domain and sub domain to  'allowed_origins' but nothing happen, still got the same error.

and this is my middleware:

```
protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];
```

middlewareGroups:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Does anyone know what is the problem? Thanks in advance.

Someone can tell me how to resolve the problem and allowed the CORS.

Comment: Have you tried this? `'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'storage/*']`

Comment: yea i do, but still got the same error. I also tried 'image/*' and got the same error.

Comment: Which Laravel version you used?

Comment: i'm using laravel 9

Comment: What happen if you remove the external package? Laravel 9 already provides the cors handling. Did you try by commenting FruitCake CORS? and then run `php artisan optimize:clear`.

Comment: actually, the error is happen even before i'm installing package fruitcake-cors

Comment: Have you made any changes inside `htaccess` file from your end?

Comment: Try putting `\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class` first in `$middleware`.